# Tkinter Canvas Collision Detection?

Tags: python, python-3.x, canvas, tkinter

I'm currently trying to make a self-scrolling adventure game, where you have to kill enemies. But for killing them, I need to know how to do collision detection. Most things I found online didn't work, my own attempts neither. 
(I'm not gonna use Pygame)

Thanks for you help in advance.

Comment: I don't know why you don't want to use Pygame, which will make this way easier. Still, you can use standard bounding box collision checking methods after getting the objects' bounding boxes using Tkinter's Canvas [bbox method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.bbox-method). As for how to do bounding box collision checking, it's a very easy implementation which can be Googled. It's built-into pygame, but since you don't want to use that, it will require a just a bit of extra work.

Comment: Yes, pygame would be the best option. i have a few great links which will really help you...http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=example_code_platformer & https://www.raywenderlich.com/24252/beginning-game-programming-for-teens-with-python these are where i learnt pygame

Comment: Show us what you've tried. Have you tried using the `find_overlapping` method on the canvas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help, but I've found an answer myself:

```
a = canvas.bbox(object)
b = canvas.bbox(object2)
if b[0] in range(a[0],a[2]) or b[2] in range(a[0],a[2]) and b[1] in range(a[1],a[3]) or b[3] in range(a[1],a[3]):
    pass #collision
```

Comment: Consider: `range(start, end)` includes `start`, but excludes `end`, so the behavior for left/top collision differs by one pixel from for the right/bottom collision. And because speed matters creating the `range` iterator and then a list to be searched for an item is not a good idea. Use `<` and `>` comparisons like `a[0]<b[0]<a[2]` instead .