# Tkinter Canvas - Checking For Character Wall Collision

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

suppose I have code like the following. I want to black blob to end the game when it touched the frame, in other words, the wall. I actually am a beginner to Tkinter Canvas so if you give a code explanation too complex I can not understand it.

```py
# Modules
from tkinter import *

# Classes
class Player:
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.master = master
        self.x = 0  # To take care of movement in "x" direction.
        self.y = 0  # To take care of movement in "y" direction.
        self.canvas = Canvas(master)  # Canvas object to create shape.
        self.rectangle = self.canvas.create_rectangle(40, 40, 25, 25, fill="black")  # Creating rectangle.
        self.canvas.pack()  # Packing the canvas.
        self.movement()  # Calling the movement method to move the rectangle.
    def movement(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.rectangle, self.x, self.y)  # This is where the move() method is called.
        """
        ⬆ This moves the rectangle to x, y coordinates.
        """
        self.canvas.after(100, self.movement)  # Gives the character a cooldown time.
    def left(self):  # For motion in negative "x" direction.
        self.x = -5
        self.y = 0
    def right(self):  # For motion in positive "x" direction.
        self.x = 5
        self.y = 0
    def down(self):  # For motion in positive "y" direction.
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 5
    def up(self):  # For motion in negative "y" direction.
        self.x = 0
        self.y = -5

# Main Window
print("How To Play\nTry to not collid the frame.")
master = Tk()
master.title("Easy Game")
master.geometry("300x75")
master.resizable(True, True)
engine = Player(master)
master.bind("<KeyPress-Left>", lambda e: engine.left())
master.bind("<KeyPress-Right>", lambda e: engine.right())
master.bind("<KeyPress-Up>", lambda e: engine.up())
master.bind("<KeyPress-Down>", lambda e: engine.down())

# Mainloop
mainloop()
```

> Thank you for further explanation.

Comment: well not sure if anybody had seen this question but btw it has gone to the deadline and I already got grounded for not finishing my homework :(

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You asked a question and expected to get an answer that solved your homework in an hour?

Comment: @JessicaYoung You can use the `bbox` method for this. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43189305/tkinter-canvas-collision-detection)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks for urgent help in doing a homework